# Mirror modifier not showing

Tags: modifiers, mirror

thanks in advance for your help. Relative blender newbie here.

I'm following a tutorial involving using the mirror modifier. Initially this mod worked fine for me and I could see a reflected version of the item I was mirroring - but now I can't get the mirrored part to show. I'm stuck right at the start of the process here.

What I've done:
-Opened new blender file
-Selected four points of the cube
-Deleted the points
-Applied mirror modifier to the remaining four-sided surface

What I've tried:
-Generating the surface from scratch instead of starting with the cube. Same result.

This does not appear to be the common issue some people experience with mirror-mods where the mod is in fact working, but appears not to be as the origin point is inside the object they have created.

Please see below for screengrab showing modifier activated on right hand side, but no mirrored version of the visible 2d plane.

Any help appreciated. Thank you.

[image: Screengrab of my blend]

Comment: maybe you've rotated your cube in Object mode, so the plane is just sticking to its mirrored image, try to apply the rotation in Object mode? If it still doesn't work please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: @moonboots It's just the axis. Billy: you have set the _Mirror_ modifier to mirror the X axis. This mirrors all vertices in -X direction to +X direction and vice versa. You have to switch to Y axis. Yeah I know, it's confusing. The chosen axis is not the axis along which the object is mirrored, it is the axis that gets mirrored, on which Minus and Plus are swapped. If you hover your mouse over the X, it says "Enable axis mirror" instead of "Enable mirror axis" ;)

Comment: @Gordon Brinkmann it should work, except if the local axis are not aligned with the global, in that case the mesh is mirroring on the X axis but as his mesh is sticking to the axis you can't see the mirrored image https://zupimages.net/up/23/06/9b22.jpg  so he must have rotated the object in Object mode and he needs to apply the rotation (or keep it but choose Y axis instead)

Comment: @moonboots Sticking to which axis? The plane in the screenshot has its median point on X = 0 and Y = 1 (and Z = 0), like when you take a default cube and delete all faces except the one in +Y direction. Without any rotation in _Object Mode_, using the _Mirror_ modifier on X will mirror the vertices (-1, 1, 1) and (-1, 1, -1) to (1, 1, 1) and (1, 1, -1) and vice versa. So the left vertices fall in place with the right vertices. That's why there is nothing to see. No rotation needs to be applied. The axis mirror needs to be changed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Strange Problem: Mirror Modifier Not Working](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/284531/strange-problem-mirror-modifier-not-working)

Comment: See the link I gave, it's exactly his situation, but as you see in my case we can see the mirrored mesh (because the local axis is aligned with the global)

Comment: @moonboots How is this the same situation? Your (original) vertices lie completely on one side of the X axis, so the mirror generates an opposite counterpart. His vertices lie symmetrical on one and the other side of the X axis, so mirroring just projects one half onto the other. So to see a mirror effect he has to either make one side on X different then the other side or switch to the Y axis.

Comment: @Gordon Brinkmann this is exactly the same situation, his mesh is aligned with X, on the opposite part of the Y axis, so he should indeed see the mirrored mesh, if he doesn't see it it must be because his local axis is now 90° to the global (and the mirrored image sticks to the original, that's why it can't be seen)

Comment: You must misunderstand what he's trying to do (or it's me), I think he's trying to do what I show in my screenshot

Comment: @moonboots Maybe he's trying to do that and I'm wrong, however your plane is placed completely different than his - but maybe he placed it wrong? This is the initial situation in the screenshot, and although all local axes are at 0° mirroring the X axis results in this: [initial situation](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18OkpgBlyFc2-AuV2sMZ2PDoEnhUe72NQ/view?usp=sharing). So switching to mirror Y gives a (to me) seemingly correct mirror result: [switched to Y](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17ZUSx9Qap0lGrud9sS78AL8F45N51SMM/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: @moonboots To get your result, the plane is placed incorrect in his screenshot - centered symmetrical on the Y axis. But if supposedly the local axis is aligned correct and he wanted to achieve your result, he could simply move the vertices on the X axis in _Edit Mode_: [your situation](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mE846wYQ76ERuScrc-fiUr3uVUUj7iSw/view?usp=sharing). Only that they would still be on Y = 1, but if that's not what he wanted why is the plane located there in the first place?

Comment: @Gordon Brinkmann It looks like we'll never know what the OP wanted  :/

Comment: Guys, thanks so much for your responses, apologies for not responding sooner. Gordon was right, I was mirroring the X axis. Thank you so much for all your help. Blender community rocks :)